# Trouble with accepts_nested_attributes_for in Rails 5.0.0.beta3, -api option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.0.0.beta3, building an API-only app using the -app option on rails new, and I am having trouble with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

In my app, a create (or a new, then a save!) of an object with nested attributes fails, with a message that the parent parent object must exist.

To test, I made a new app and used just the test case with members and posts in the [ANAF documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :posts  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts  
end
```

and

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :member
end
```

(These class definitions were generated by the Rails scaffold generator, so the inherit from ApplicationRecord, rather than ActiveRecord::Base, but per [this post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html), that is not significant.)

With those classed defined, and matching migrations created and run, I launch a Rails console and follow the steps in the doc:

```
params = { member: {
name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { title: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
]}}  

{:member=>{:name=>"joe", :posts_attributes=>[{:title=>"Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!"}, {:title=>"The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen"}, {:title=>"", :_destroy=>"1"}]}}
```

And then:

```
>> member = Member.create(params[:member])
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
#<Member id: nil, name: "joe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

No joy!

When I split the create into new, then save!, I get the same result, with a somewhat clearer error:

```
>> member = Member.new(params[:member])  
#<Member id: nil, name: "joe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

> > member.save!
> >        (15.0ms)  BEGIN
> >     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Posts member must exist
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
> >
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in`save!'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in`block in save!'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:233:in`block in transaction'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:233:in`transaction'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/activerecord/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in`save!'
> >         from (irb):14
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4  /bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in`start'
> >      (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in`run_command!'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/command.rb:20:in `run'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/rails-b785064958f9/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/Documents/Projects/Active/Rails/curious/doko/m.0/test_anaf/bin/rails:9:in `require'
> >         from /Users/pauldavis/Documents/Projects/Active/Rails/curious/doko/m.0/test_anaf/bin/rails:9:in`'
> >         from -e:1:in `load'
> >         from -e:1:in`'

Any thoughts on why this sample code in the documentation is be working? Could something be wrong in my environment? Does the -api option break something in ActiveRecord? BTW, I am using PostgreSQL

Thanks!

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for some hours, but I found a solution today, in this helpful [blog post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html).  

I think the `optional:` parameter should be mentioned in the docs, because it is required to make the code work as shown.  

Perhaps the docs should also be updated changing the superclass to ApplicationRecord, too, though that seems less compelling.

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered the same problem.
It seems specification has been changed from Rails 5.
By putting the option, and the previous and the same operation.

[belongs_to should default to required: true #18233](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233)

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member, optional: true
end
```

It is my clumsy may speak English, but ...

Comment: This had me stumped for like... three hours. Awesome. It's finally over...

Comment: Actually, this isn't the real issue. The problem is a genuine bug with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Rails 5 versions < 5.1.1.

Comment: See Henrique Jensen's answer. (Solution: upgrade to Rails 5.1.1)

Comment: thanks. it works. Also upgrading to rails 5.1.2 works well.

Answer (score 5):

This is a regression reported as [rails#25198](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25198). As was pointed out, you may use `inverse_of` as a workaround.

It is planned to be fixed in 5.0.1.

Comment: About the fix in 5.0.1: I can report it is still happening with 5.2. The workaround you proposed does solve the problem though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the solution in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233

Just add

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :member, required: false
end
```

It seems a problem with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Rails 5, so you need add `required: false` to your child models.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the `inverse_of` options to the associations allowed `accepts_nested_attributes` to work. Nice than monkey patching, still allows the association to be validated

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing problems with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as well in my Rails 5 beta 3 app and seems like it is buggy. Ideally, a bug report should be submitted, but we didn't have time to do it properly. We have the following setup:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
```

Eventually, we had to monkey-patch the method inside the model like this:

```
  def attachments_attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.reject! do |_attachment|  
      if _attachment = Attachment.find(_attachment['id'])
        if _attachment.drop_id.nil?
          attachments << _attachment
          next true
        end
      end
      next false
    end
    # assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(:attachments, attributes)
  end
```

The only thing is that the last (commented-out line) with `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association` has some issues, but hopefully this will provide you an idea how this can be fixed.